# How to use 'on_send' method of Nickel response?

Tags: rust, nickel

On a nickel web service I would like to execute a function when a response send finishes.
I've found the 'on_send' method on [this doc](http://docs.nickel.rs/nickel/struct.Response.html#method.on_send), but I can't get it to build.

I get this error:

> type mismatch: the type `[closure@src/models/plugins/session.rs:78:22: 78:31 x:_]` implements the trait `std::ops::FnMut<()>`, but the trait `for<'r> std::ops::FnMut<(&'r mut nickel::Response<'_, D>,)>` is required (expected tuple, found ())

and this one

> type mismatch: the type `[closure@src/models/plugins/session.rs:78:22: 78:31 x:_]` implements the trait `std::ops::FnOnce<()>`, but the trait `for<'r> std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r mut nickel::Response<'_, D>,)>` is required (expected tuple, found ())

My code sample is

```
let mut x: usize = 1;
let update = || x += 2 ;
res.on_send(update);
```

Where `res` is `&mut Response<'mw, D>`

Comment: Could you include a complete example which can be compiled to reproduce this error?  The error does explain the problem, though - it's expecting a function/closure which takes an `&'r mut Response` but you're giving it a closure which doesn't take any arguments.  Does `|_| x+=2` work?

Comment: The "expected tuple" may be a bit confusing.  I'm not sure why it says that, as the expected type is a `Response` which isn't a tuple. Full code example would definitely help, as the errors look a bit odd too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Nickel, but the error is telling you that your closure implements the trait

```
std::ops::FnOnce<()>
```

but the argument to `on_send` needs to be

```
for<'r> std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r mut nickel::Response<'_, D>,)>
```

Without a complete code example, it's hard to give you a working answer. But the right answer will be something similar to this:

```
let update = |_| x += 2;
```

You aren't using the tuple argument, so you can mark it unused with `_`. But you must specify it or else the types do not match up.